# Flask Admin - Only include inline_models in Create View and NOT Edit View

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have been trying for a while and have not been able to figure this out. It sounds like a simple problem and I'm sure it's just me...so sure you will be able to help.

I basically want to only have an inline model display when I am in Create View (Creating a new entry) and NOT when I'm in Edit View (Editing an existing entry).

Comment: Anyone got any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `form_edit_rules` and remove the field of the inline model.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide an example for how one would do that? Thanks!